# Exporting Output from Model Summary in R

Tags: r, output

Is there a way to export the output from a summary procedure in R (similar to ods output in SAS)?

I have this time series:

```
summary(ets(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 12)))
```

And when you run this you get all kinds of great information like MAPE and RMSE.  I want to selectively assign some of these metrics to variables for use in other processes further down the line.

```
MAPE.ets <- [some bit of code that takes the MAPE from the output and pops it right here]
```

Is there a way in R to do this?

EDIT:  I realized after some answers that stlf ets behaves differently than ets, and I need a solution to work for stlf ets as well.

```
summary(stlf(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 4)))
```

Comment: Thank Sotos, I had never heard of the broom package but looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply assign the summary to a new object. This creates a matrix in which the metrics you mentioned can be accessed:

```
summ <- summary(ets(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 12)))

summ[,"MAPE"]
[1] 44.51514
```

**EDIT:**

The intended way in the forecast package appears to be the use of the `accuracy` method (the `summary` method for the `ets`-class actually calls `accuracy`); and this will work for both `ets` and `stlf` :

```
res2 <- stlf(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 4))
acc <- accuracy(res2)
acc[,"MAPE"]
```

Comment: This works for ets, but editied question to reflect an oversight on my end.  Apologies.  Is there a way to generalize this as it does not seem to want to work for stlf()?

Answer (score 1):

The summary gives you a vector. You can get MAPE like this if you want colnames and rownames.

```
out <-summary(ets(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), 
              start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 12)))
out[,5,drop=FALSE]

             MAPE
Training set 44.51514
```

I you only want the number, remove `drop=FALSE`

```
out[5]
[1] 44.51514
```

**EDIT** Using `stfl`, it is better to use the `accuracy` function instead of `summary`. To get MAPE, you can do:

```
res <- stlf(ts(c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100, 200, 100, 120, 300), 
            start = c(2009, 1), frequency = 4))
accuracy(res)[5]
[1] 44.5994
```

Comment: This works for ets, but editied question to reflect an oversight on my end.  Apologies.  Is there a way to generalize this as it does not seem to want to work for stlf()?

Comment: @DavidHeckmann We should start a synchronised swimming team :)

Comment: Hey guys.  I really appreciate both of your answers.  I'm going with David's only because I like the feature of asking for the metric explicitly by name rather than location, but both are excellent explanations and answers.

Comment: One question, so that I can learn how to be more self sufficient for this type of stuff...where did you find the list of outputs for the procedures?  Is there a resource that you can point me to?  Or is it just something you knew from experience?  I know I will run into this issue with other procedures, and want to know how to list all output created by a procedure, so that I can see what's available.  Help documentation doesn't seem to have this info...

Comment: @pyll Usually, you can try `str(res)` to see what is the structure or the element. In this case, it doesn't work however...